# Android Map zoom to overlay item

Tags: android

I am trying to use the Google maps API on my android app. I have set an overlay item  at a particular geopoint co-ordinate. On opening the activity, it uses the default mapview of the google map with the correct location of the  overlay item for that geotpoint. My question is, how do I set the view to be zoomed in for that geopoint so one would actually see the location in a better fashion rather than having to manually zoom in by tracing the overlay item. I wish to zoom it so I can see the local area so the user can at least derive useful information from it. 
My code is as follows:

/*---- HelloItemizedOverlay.java -------*/

```
public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
Context mContext;

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay)
{
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
      super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
      mContext = context;
    }


@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mOverlays.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
  OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
  AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
  dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
  dialog.show();
  return true;
}
}
```

/*---- MainActivity.java ---- */

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MapView view = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.themap);
    view.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    final GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!");

    GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(35410000, 139460000);
    OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Sekai, konichiwa!", "I'm in Japan!");


    final MapController control = view.getController();
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            control.setCenter(point);
        }
    };

    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = view.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);


    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);




}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: for your `MapView` try `view.getController().zoomToSpan(latSpanE6, lonSpanE6)`

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem: If you mean adding the line in this way: view.getController().zoomToSpan(19240000, -99120000); 
then this zoomed to a different location than my overlay item. Plus, this isn't still zoomed. I actually need to zoom it much beyond like youcould see the local streets and buildings.

Comment: Android does not use the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@noobcoder I have used the same example, and if i get your question right, you can use the following method to zoom to a particular point.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController#animateTo(com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint, java.lang.Runnable)

It worked at least for me.

Comment: It worked man. I used controller.setZoom(15) and it zoomed perfectly. Thanks. But I have another small question, Where do I get the location co-ordinates of a particular location ? Is there a list of a few locations with their resp. latitudes and longitudes somewhere ?

Comment: okay ! for that u need to use the [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)`location manager` class.

first get the location service by using getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE). This returns a locationManager object. 

Now call this method [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String))'getLastKnownLocation' to get the current location.

For a location of some other town, say Kolkata, use wikipedia to get the location coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

```
view = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.themap);
mapController = view.getController();

point = new GeoPoint((int) (38.897089* 1E6), (int) (-77.051437* 1E6));

mapControler .animateTo(point );
mapControler .setZoom(17);    //Set zoom level as you want..,.
```

Try this..,.

Comment: It worked. Now, how do I set the co-ordinates of GeoPoint like :
point = new GeoPoint(38.897089,-77.051437);
Cuz it doesnt accept double values. I tried but gave me an error.

Comment: It went to a different location.

Comment: Oops...!! my bad. That worked. I did a minor mistake. but that worked for me. Thanks man